# Working with PyDev on multi-computers

Tags: python, pydev

I try to figure out the best way to work with Python/PyDev on multi-computers. At the moment I try to write a code at my windows machine at work and do it also at home on my linux machine. I saw somewhere an IDE with version management, although do not know exactly how it worked in practice. Is there a way to work in PyDev on the same code on two different computers?

In future we plan to set up a team for the project so will have a few people working on the same project at the time. I try to find some information through the web, but did not meet anything sensible.

Comment: You mean like source-control? Where you have code that you can access/store/retrieve from a central server and also have it be able to track changes that people are making? Something like [git](http://git-scm.com) as in [github](http://github.com)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) for version control. This is supported under Eclipse by the [MercurialEclipse](http://javaforge.com/project/HGE) plugin, which is available from the Eclipse marketplace.

How to set it up depends on whether you can access your work computer from home or not. If you do you can set up your home computer as a server, pull from the server what you did at work and push to the server what you do at home. Otherwise there are means to extract modifications from one computer and apply them to the other and viceversa.